# How can i use a single namespace for multiple imported modules?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns, import

Is it possible to have a single namespace for multiple imported modules ?, i wanna do something like this:

```
import {moduleA, moduleB, moduleC} as ModuleManager from 'AllMyModules.js';
```

So i can avoid conflicts such as module and class function having the same name, for example :

```
moduleA = () => {
}

doSomething = () => {
   ModuleManager.moduleA();
   moduleA();
}
```

Of course that is not all, giving the modules a namespace also improves readability and helps me know where a function or module is coming from and for what purpose.

**Please note** that i already know about:

```
import * as ModuleManager from 'AllMyModules.js'
```

And this is not what i'm looking for !, i don't want `ModuleManager` to include everything, there are three reasons for this:
1-When i specify the modules like `{moduleA, moduleB, moduleC}` with one look i'm able to tell what kinda of modules this file is usins.
2-It prevents me from using modules i shouldn't by mistake (specially when your modules are some services that get some data, its easy to make mistakes)
3-I presume only importing what i need is lighter and helps with less bundle size ?, well i'm not sure about this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can import with `*`, though this will import the whole `AllMyModules` namespace, not just the ones you select:

```
import * as ModuleManager from 'AllMyModules.js';
// ...
ModuleManager.moduleA();
```

If you want an object with only *some* modules, not all, and none of the exports are mutable (which exports *shouldn't* be anyway), then to keep the code DRY, extract what you want into a new object after importing:

```
import * as ModuleManagerNS from 'AllMyModules.js';
const ModuleManager = {};
for (const prop of ['moduleA', 'moduleB', 'moduleC']) {
  ModuleManager[prop] = ModuleManagerNS[prop];
}
ModuleManager.moduleA();
```

If you want to avoid ever using `import *`, you can also rename the imports while importing to avoid name collisions, though it looks pretty WET:

```
import {moduleA as moduleManagerModuleA, moduleB as moduleManagerModuleB, moduleC as moduleManagerModuleC} from 'AllMyModules.js';
const ModuleManager = {
  moduleA: moduleManagerModuleA,
  moduleB: moduleManagerModuleB,
  moduleC: moduleManagerModuleC,
}
```

I'd strongly prefer using `import *` instead.

> I presume only importing what i need is lighter and helps with less bundle size ?, well i'm not sure about this one.

It can. If you have modules with exports which will go completely unused, this [can help with tree-shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/), though you have to tediously list each export name, like in the above snippet.

Comment: Your answer is surely a possible solution, but it require at least a couple of lines of code, i wished there was a simpler solution, I don't understand why there isn't something like : `import {moduleA, moduleB, moduleC} as ModuleManager from 'AllMyModules.js'` :d

Comment: The conciseness you're looking for [just isn't part of the `import` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Syntax), unfortunately

Comment: I kinda already knew that, but i thought maybe a library or some kinda of Webpack configuration or something makes such a thing possible, so i thought i should ask, thanks.